# Find the default Page (i.e index.php/default.aspx) for a URL in http Request

Tags: c#, http-headers

I am just wondering if there is a way to find out a sites default page (i.e. index.php, default.aspx or custom!) automatically through a http request or similar in C#. I have looked in the header response and there doesn't seem to be anything which gives this information.

Any help would be great!

Comment: its all managed by web server may may be not possible to every time `index.php` or `Default.aspx` is a default page if you want to set `something.html` as a defualt page you can set..  or if you want to check which is a default page you can to manually hit with page like `www.foo.com/default.aspx` .

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of that. I have considered checking for the most common default page types manually if it is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there is no such thing as a default page. Just a page that happens to be in the root directory or that you are directed to when you request the root. It'll certainly not be in a request, because then you would already know. That would be like sending someone a letter to tell them what street they live in.
A server might send you a redirect response when you request the root of the website, if so, then you will know what it considers to be it's own 'default page', if not, you'll have to asume its just the root itself.

Comment: Redirects seem to be URLs not the actual files that form them (URL rewrite modules scuppering that plan). Good analogy with the letter though! I think it may be impossible without having access to a web.config or httpaccess file for the site

Comment: If you really want to know the name of the actual file (or files) that generated a page, that is indeed impossible. A server can serve you anything it wants and gather a response from wherever it wants, it doesn't even have to take your actual request into account. So unless the server wants to tell you everything (and you trust it's telling the truth), you just don't know.